# How do you make a generic memoize function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, memoization

I've seen [the other post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129877/how-do-i-write-a-generic-memoize-function), but is there a clean way of doing this in Haskell?

As a 2nd part, can it also be done without making the function monadic?

Comment: I can barely spell Haskell :), but I don't think so.

Memoization involves exactly the kind of static state that pure functional languages don't allow, as I understand them.

Of course, using a monad would make this doable, I think.  But your 2nd part kind of indicates that you know that already.

Comment: @Mike: I might have thought the same thing, but actually functional languages can do memoization well, as the answers show. They just have to pass the state around via function parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This largely follows http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization.

You want a function of type (a -> b).  If it doesn't call itself, then
you can just write a simple wrapper that caches the return values.  The 
best way to store this mapping depends on what properties of a you can
exploit.  Ordering is pretty much a minimum.  With integers 
you can construct an infinite lazy list or tree holding the values.

```
type Cacher a b = (a -> b) -> a -> b

positive_list_cacher :: Cacher Int b
positive_list_cacher f n = (map f [0..]) !! n
```

or

```
integer_list_cacher :: Cacher Int b
integer_list_cacher f n = (map f (interleave [0..] [-1, -2, ..]) !!
    index n where
        index n | n < 0  = 2*abs(n) - 1
        index n | n >= 0 = 2 * n
```

So, suppose it is recursive.  Then you need it to call not itself, but
the memoized version, so you pass that in instead:

```
f_with_memo :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f_with_memo memoed base = base_answer
f_with_memo memoed arg  = calc (memoed (simpler arg))
```

The memoized version is, of course, what we're trying to define.

But we can start by creating a function that caches its inputs:

We could construct one level by passing in a function that creates a 
structure that caches values.  Except we need to create the version of f
that *already has* the cached function passed in.

Thanks to laziness, this is no problem:

```
memoize cacher f = cached where
         cached = cacher (f cached)
```

then all we need is to use it:

```
exposed_f = memoize cacher_for_f f
```

The article gives hints as to how to use a type class selecting on the 
input to the function to do the above, rather than choosing an explicit 
caching function.  This can be really nice -- rather than explicitly 
constructing a cache for each combination of input types, we can implicitly
combine caches for types a and b into a cache for a function taking a and b.

One final caveat: using this lazy technique means the cache never shrinks,
it only grows.  If you instead use the IO monad, you can manage this, but
doing it wisely depends on usage patterns.

Comment: I read the link.  I guess you would have to create a new type class and implement its interface for any type you'd like to be memoized.  Is there any way to code that once in the Memoize module to save work for users of this module?

Comment: You can code up common types to cache on, and a few rules for combining them.  If they use types you haven't defined, they'll need to create instances themselves.

Comment: You can also create instances based on type classes such as Ord or Bound, but each should really be put in separate modules -- they may need a different caching scheme, so need the option to not use these.

Answer (score 16):

The package data-memocombinators on hackage provides lots of reusable memoization routines.  The basic idea is:

```
type Memo a = forall r. (a -> r) -> (a -> r)
```

I.e. it can memoize any function from a.  The module then provides some primitives (like `unit :: Memo ()` and `integral :: Memo Int`), and combinators for building more complex memo tables (like `pair :: Memo a -> Memo b -> Memo (a,b)` and `list :: Memo a -> Memo [a]`).

Answer (score 12):

You can modify Jonathan´s solution with unsafePerformIO to create a "pure" memoizing version of your function.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe

memoize :: Ord a => (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
memoize f = unsafePerformIO $ do 
    r <- newIORef Map.empty
    return $ \ x -> unsafePerformIO $ do 
        m <- readIORef r
        case Map.lookup x m of
            Just y  -> return y
            Nothing -> do 
                    let y = f x
                    writeIORef r (Map.insert x y m)
                    return y
```

This will work with recursive functions:

```
fib :: Int -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib_memo (n-1) + fib_memo (n-2)

fib_memo :: Int -> Integer
fib_memo = memoize fib
```

Altough this example is a function with one integer parameter, the type of memoize tells us that it can be used with any function that takes a comparable type. If you have a function with more than one parameter just group them in a tuple before applying memoize. F.i.:

```
f :: String -> [Int] -> Float
f ...

f_memo = curry (memoize (uncurry f))
```

Comment: This is very nice. It would probably be helpful for newbies, if you could also show the import statements needed.

Comment: There is no need for `unsafePerformIO`. The same code be performed in ST monad.

Comment: @uhbif19 Is that so?  I challenge you to write it (with the final pure `(a -> b)` intact)

Answer (score 3):

Doing a direct translation from the more imperative languages, I came up with this.

```
memoize :: Ord a => (a -> IO b) -> IO (a -> IO b)
memoize f =
  do r <- newIORef Map.empty
     return $ \x -> do m <- readIORef r
                       case Map.lookup x m of
                            Just y  -> return y
                            Nothing -> do y <- f x
                                          writeIORef r (Map.insert x y m)
                                          return y
```

But this is somehow unsatisfactory.  Also, [Data.Map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html) constrains the parameter to be an instance of [Ord](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Ord.html).

Comment: Of course there is no way to avoid some sort of constraint, be it implicit or explicit.  How would you memoize a function of type (Integer -> Bool) -> Bool, for example?

Answer (score 1):

If your arguments are going to be natural numbers, you can do simply:

```
memo f = let values = map f [0..]
     in \n -> values !! n
```

However, that doesn't really help you with the stack overflowing, and it doesn't work with recursive calls. You can see some fancier solutions at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization.

Comment: This is helpful, but I still feel like there could be something more general.