# Is it possible to find out how many named arguments does a function expect?

Tags: function, parameters, lua, argument-passing

In JavaScript, you can [ask a function object how many arguments does it expect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length). Is the same thing possible in Lua?

Comment: For a function implemented in Lua, you can also get a "signature" of sorts. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24216007/2226988) to [Is there a way to determine the signature of a Lua function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/142417/2226988).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Lua 5.2, you can use `debug.getinfo(f).nparams`.

(answer edited in light of Luiz's answer, previous answer was correct only for Lua 5.1)

Comment: You should also add that __ANY__ number of arguments can be passed to a function in lua.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `debug` library:

```
print(debug.getinfo(f).nparams)
```