# Caching expensive table calculation on strings between separate function calls in Lua

Tags: lua

I have a number of functions operating on strings to extract interesting properties from those strings. One particular function which is called by many of those functions is very expensive and ultimately generates a table of values:

```
local function expensive(s)
  local t = nil
  return function()
    if not t then
      t = {}
      -- some expensive operations with s which add items to t
    end
    return t
  end
end

local function fn1(s)
  local t = expensive(s)
  -- some other fast operations using t and s
end

local function fn2(s)
  local t = expensive(s)
  -- some other fast operations using t and s
end

local s1, s2 = 'a', 'b'
fn1(s1) -- should create the 't' table for s1
fn1(s2) -- should create the 't' table for s2
fn2(s1) -- should not create the 't' table again for s1
fn1(s2) -- should also not create the 't' table again for s2
```

How can I make it so that the expensive function creates the table exactly once per string, returning the table in either case? I would rather not have the table exposed to the global environment. I think this could probably be accomplished by some clever use of closures, but I don't know the construct well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Egor's answer will do the job, but the `cache` table is accessible by the whole file. To hide it, you have a couple of options. The first is a simple do/end block.

```
local expensive
do
    local cache = {}
    expensive = function (s)
      local t = cache[s]
      if not t then
        t = {}
        -- some expensive operations with s which add items to t
        cache[s] = t
      end
      return t
    end
end
```

The other is a self-executing function.

```
local expensive = (function ()
    local cache = {}
    return function (s)
      local t = cache[s]
      if not t then
        t = {}
        -- some expensive operations with s which add items to t
        cache[s] = t
      end
      return t
    end
end)()
```

The self-executing function has the advantage that you only have to define the `expensive` function name once, but the disadvantage that it is a little harder to read than the do/end block. Otherwise they are pretty much the same.

Comment: The do ... end block is clever! They have a similar example in the lua reference manual but I hadn't thought of using it in this case.

Answer (score 4):

```
local cache = {}

local function expensive(s)
  local t = cache[s]
  if not t then
    t = {}
    -- some expensive operations with s which add items to t
    cache[s] = t
  end
  return t
end
```

Comment: This is the solution I initially developed, but the cache is exposed to the script environment which isn't ideal. Jack's answer offers two solutions around this.

Comment: `cache` is not in global environment

Comment: Fair enough. I mean the script's environment.

Comment: That is "lexical scope"

Answer (score 2):

You can use "memoization" to cache the values returned by the function depending on the parameters. You can read [a chapter on it in Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/17.1.html) and use one of the memoization modules that do the work for you, for example, [memoize](https://github.com/kikito/memoize.lua).

See also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129877/how-do-i-write-a-generic-memoize-function) for related interesting solutions.